# Buttons in StackView not working - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uistackview

My problem is that the buttons in my Stackview don't work. I configured 6 buttons in Storyboard (user Interaction is enabled) and put them all in a stackview because I need them to organize automatically, when I hide one or more of the Buttons. But I have the problem that when I touch one of the Buttons nothing happens, not even an error. When pulling one of the buttons outside of the Stackview and put in anywhere on the screen it works. Do I have to configure the stack view in a special way to enable buttons to be touched or what did I miss?

Comment: in storyboard or code ??

Comment: I configured the Buttons and the Stackview in Storyboards, but could also do it in code.

Comment: set userInteractionEnabled to true

Comment: Unfortunately it is already enabled. So this can't be the solution :/

Comment: show hierarchy on viewcontroller

Comment: @TomaszCzyżak The stack view is in the front of the view controller (in front of all other images/etc..) is it that what you mean?

Comment: viewcontroller->view->stackview ?

Comment: yes. exactly like this but more like view controller -> view -> image, etc. and at last the stack view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me see attached screenshot...

[image]

Comment: Omg I am so stupid. I made my navigation bar transparent and put the buttons exactly on the navigation bar but without recognizing it. Sorry for this dumb question.